# MySql optimizer doesn't use the index on varchar

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, percona, mysql-5.6

I have a table defined as

```
CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prodcode` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `error` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ctime` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `mtime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `event` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `article_prodcode_idx` (`prodcode`),
  KEY `article_status_idx` (`status`),
  KEY `article_priority_idx` (`priority`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This table contains about 40 million of record.
When I run a query like

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE prodcode='a-4536-x-bef45-green';
```

the optimizer "decides" that such query doesn't have to use any index (an "EXPLAIN SELECT..." results in a

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | article  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 39415251 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

If I add e.g. another field like priority or status, the optimizer uses just such indexes, but NOT the article_prodcode_idx one. The problem is that the query scans the whole 40 million records, and the result comes after 100 seconds. Why the index is not used there?

I checked this answer too: [MySQL partial indexes on varchar fields and group by optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588280/mysql-partial-indexes-on-varchar-fields-and-group-by-optimization) but I didn't find any answer to my problem. What should I do to let the query return results... quickly?

Thank you

Comment: How many rows are selected with your query?

Comment: @akina None, one or two.

Comment: Is charset conversion involved somwehere?

Comment: @Salman No, there are no charset issues. Content is plain ascii even if generic charset is utf8. Field1 can contain utf8 strings, but not the indexed one.

Comment: Add index hint (FORCE INDEX).

Comment: @Akina FORCE_INDEX is going to be deprecated after MySQL 8:

"Thus, you should expect USE INDEX, FORCE INDEX, and IGNORE INDEX to be deprecated in 
a future release of MySQL, and at some time thereafter to be removed altogether." Indeed, I'll explore this direction, thanks.

Comment: No problems, use `INDEX_MERGE` [Index-Level Optimizer Hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-index-level)

Comment: It does not work: the optimizer still doesn't use such an index. I tried both ones.

Comment: This is very strange indeed. Doublecheck your table definition with `SHOW CREATE TABLE article`. Grasping at explanations: try `ANALYZE TABLE article` to rework the index stats and try again.  And try `ANALYZE SELECT ...` or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ...` (which one depends on MySQL version) to show actual execution stats.

Comment: @O.Jones I used the SHOW CREATE TABLE article to prepare the question. The "ANALYZE TABLE article" reports status OK, and it's really quick. The ANALYZE SELECT is not working on my mysql version (5.6.40 - Percona cluster rel84), just the EXPLAIN SELECT (that still shows no use of indexes). I was wondering if it's a problem related to the size of the DB, maybe the index is too big...  no idea :( Thank you.

Comment: The table definition in your question says `PRIMARY KEY (oid)` but you have no such column in the table. I still suggest doublechecking your table definition on your production server. Rule out a missing index as the cause of the problem.

Comment: Try `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Comment: @O.Jones my fault, I just removed a list of 6 other int/boolean fields and probably I added a char changing the oid/id in table definition. Edited.

Comment: *NOTE* today I tried the same exact query as yesterday, but now the index is used!! Is it possible that this is a temporary issue due e.g. to Percona cluster that is NOT using indexes e.g. when it's replicating or updating indexes, or something like that?

Comment: Well, now, I stand by my statement that this is strange. Glad it's working.

Comment: I found where is the trick. It was my fault, mixing different query formats and results.
Sometimes I did "SET @pc='a-4536-x-bef45-green'" then a "EXPLAIN SELECT... WHERE prodcode=@pc" and NO index is used in this case. But if I use ...WHERE prodcode='a-4536-x-bef45-green' then index is used. I have part of my code script using the variables other with fixed strings: what is the difference?? Why @var does not involve indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep check, I solved the problem. In some ways, I did a mistake in describing the problem. In fact, in my script, I had something like

```
SET @pc='a-4536-x-bef45-green'; 
...
SELECT * FROM article WHERE prodcode=@pc;
```

while in some other points I had

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE prodcode='a-4536-x-bef45-green';
```

In the first case, no indexes are used. In the second one, everything works as expected.
This is the explain of the first query:

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT * FROM article WHERE prodcode=@pc;
{
  "query_block": {
  "select_id": 1,
  "table": {
    "table_name": "article",
    "access_type": "ALL",
    "rows": 39498773,
    "filtered": 100,
    "attached_condition": "(convert(`shop`.`article`.`prodcode` using utf8mb4) = (@`pc`))"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the second one

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT * FROM article WHERE prodcode='a-4536-x-bef45-green';

{
"query_block": {
  "select_id": 1,
  "table": {
    "table_name": "article",
    "access_type": "ref",
    "possible_keys": [
      "article_prodcode_idx"
    ],  
    "key": "article_prodcode_idx",
    "used_key_parts": [
      "prodcode"
    ],
    "key_length": "194",
    "ref": [
      "const"
    ],
    "rows": 2,
    "filtered": 100,
    "index_condition": "(`shop`.`article`.`prodcode` = 'a-4536-x-bef45-green')"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried a lot of times, using e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE prodcode in (@pc, 'another code');
```

but the result is always the same: if a variable is involved, NO indexes are used.

Knowing, that, I changed my scripts in order to not use SET anymore, and everything started running fine.

I still would like to know why... but at least the problem is solved.

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032641/mysql-query-dontt-uses-index-when-there-are-variables-in-where?noredirect=1&lq=1